# Spring 1 with Junit 4

Tags: spring, junit4

I am trying to Unit test of spring 1 service method but during execution fetching "bean is undefined" .. so my concern is that Is it possible to load spring 1 beans in Junit 4 test file with below code

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)  
@ContextConfiguration ("/someclasspath/applcationContextOfSpring1.xml")
```

Or is there any other way to use Junit 4 and Spring 1 together ?

Comment: Spring 1? No that doesn't have JUnit4 support, also if this class is available you are basically mixing Spring versions which you should never do.

Comment: thanks for your reply ..i really need help right now so can you suggest me any other Unit testing framework for Spring 1 ?

Comment: JUnit will work fine, but you cannot use the annotations, you have to do it manually. Use on the the supported test classes (as explained in the spring reference guide). Also why are yu still on Spring 1?

Comment: Currently i am working on 6 or 7 Years old Product...they have not yet thought about migrating it to spring 4..so i have to integrate Junit with spring 1...so without annotation it is possible to use it but how can i find the beans in JUnit test file ...how can execute it successfully ?...Mockito support work with Spring 1?

Comment: As stated, read the reference guide. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/

Comment: Unfortunately, you will have to do it the hard way. Probably you'll need to utilize `@Before` or even `@BeforeClass` to load your spring context (or whatever it was back then) manually and get the beans from there. This manual loading should also you to use a specific test configuration, if you desire, which could include mock objects (at least, if Spring 1 supports static factory methods). Otherwise, I don't see why Mockito, etc. shouldn't work.

Comment: thanks @FlorianSchaetz for reply ... do i need to create another spring context test-application-context.xml separate from main application-context.xml file or i can use use the existing main context file? ...any link where i can find code to load spring context in BeforeClass or Before annotated methods ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have never used Spring 1, but according to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/1.2.9/reference/beans.html), (Spring 1.2.9) something like this should work...

```
public class MyTest {

    private MyBean myBean; // The spring bean you want to test

    @Before
    public void initBean() {
       ClassPathResource res = new ClassPathResource("application-context.xml");
       XmlBeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(res);
       this.myBean = factory.getBean("myBean", MyBean.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_something() {
        ...
    }
}
```

There are other ways according to the documentation, but this seems to be the easiest. On how to use the BeanFactory itself, you can refer to this [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean%28java.lang.String%29).